# remove specific item range from list

Tags: android, flutter, api, drop-down-menu, dropdown

i have 2 dropdowns 1st is toDate and 2nd is fromDate with 1 list of months to be displayed.

```
List<String> month = [
'January',
'February',
'March',
'April',
'May',
'June',
'July',
'August',
'September',
'October',
'November',
'December',
];
```

in the first dropdown, all the list is shown to select but in the 2nd dropdown, I want to show all values coming after the selected 1st dropdown value.

for example - :
in the first dropdown, I selected 'March' the 2nd dropdown the list displayed should be after 'March'.

How do I do it?
please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
void main() {
  List<String> month = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December',
  ];
  var choice = 'March';
  var ind = month.indexOf(choice);
  if (ind > 0) {
    print(month.skip(ind + 1));
  }
}
```

Comment: what if i want previous value rather than after value?

Comment: @palak `month.getRange(0, ind)`

Comment: @palak you can find API document in https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/getRange.html